# LazyVerticalGrid extremely poor performance even in release build with isMinifyEnabled (again)

Tags: performance, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Recently I found out about [ApkUpdater](https://github.com/rumboalla/apkupdater) open source app and wanted to use it as light alternative to Google Play. But the page with list of installed apps is extremely lagging when scrolling, especially if doing it rapidly. Turns out the app was using `LazyVericalGrid` for that purpose. I was thinking that its elements are too complex for rendering (mostly images), but decided to test it myself.

Here's my test code:

```kotlin
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.GridCells
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.LazyVerticalGrid
import androidx.compose.material3.Text

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            LazyVerticalGrid(GridCells.Fixed(5))
                { items(1000) { i->Text("$i") } }
        }
    }
}
```

`build.gradle.kts`:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.2.1" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.22" apply false
}
```

In `app/build.gradle.kts`:

```
...
kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.8"
...
```

```
...
buildTypes {
    release {
        isMinifyEnabled = true
        ...
    }
}
...
```

It badly stutters both on a14 emulator and on a13 real device (poco x3 pro running crdroid v9.7).
I looked over the all links from first google page about `LazyVerticalGrid` lagging and that's what other people recommend:

- try running release version of your app
- add a key to the items of grid

So, my brain is blowing up. How that simple code can bring so much performance issues? Am I doing something (completely) wrong? Does something causes repeated recomposition on every frame? Or is it `LazyVerticalGrid` actually being still not quite optimized?